# Dismissing ProgressDialog in another method

Tags: android, progressdialog

Here's my code for showing ProgressDialog:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
pd.setTitle("");
pd.setMessage("Sending...");
pd.show();
```

I want to dismiss the ProgressDialog in another method but when I put
    pd.dismiss();
there will be an error with pd.

> pd cannot be resolved.

Any way to make it possible? Thankyou.

Comment: Make pd a member variable

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare ProgressDialog is a single object.Then you can used it anywhere on your class .You can try this code.

For initials start loading step:

```
public ProgressDialog pDialog;
public void showProgress()
{
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        pDialog.setMessage(msg);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
}
```

For cancel ProgressDialog are:

```
public void cancleProgress()
{
      if(pDialog!=null)
         pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring `ProgressDialog pd` within the scope of a method.

have `ProgressDialog pd` withing the class itself and in the above code just have `pd = ....`

then you should be able to use `pd` elsewhere in your code.

Comment: ohh, I see the comments now, but still, leaving this because the explanation might help.

Comment: Okay I'll try it. Thanks